# Custom splash images not appearing in LaunchImage.launchimage folder in Ionic 3 project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, splash-screen, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a new Ionic (v3) project and want to add spash screen to support iPhone XS max and XR. The problem that I am facing inspite of declaring the path and other specs required to get the splash image for a particular device in `config.xml` is that I could not see the same image in my `ios` platform's **LaunchImage.launchimage** folder. This makes problem as Xcode reads from the mentioned folder where it could not find my custom splash image.

My `config.xml` looks like:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>remote</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />

    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />

    <!-- My custom image that is not visible -->
    <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default.png" width="1242" />

</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
<engine name="ios" spec="latest" />
```

My question is why I cannot see **Default.png** in my platform's **launchimage** folder? I have also tried with name **Default-Portrait-2688h@3x.png**. I have removed my splash screen plugin and reinstalled it. Using ios `latest` spec as well. Please help.